# Criar procedure no phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando criar um procedure que altera entre insert e update no phpmyadmin mas me retorna um erro na linha do if EXISTS, depois tentei criar pelo painel grafico e me retorna erro na ultima linha sempre... Alguém sabe oque está errado?

Erro quando tento pelo painel(Sem sql)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro quando tento por sql
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SEND_ITEMS(
  IN i_item_id int(11), 
  IN i_customer_id VARCHAR(11),
  IN i_quantity SMALLINT)
  AS
  BEGIN
  IF(EXISTS(SELECT item_id,customer_id FROM wpcheap_items_selected WHERE (item_id = i_item_id AND customer_id = i_customer_id)))
 THEN Update wpcheap_items_selected SET quantity = i_quantity WHERE (item_id = i_item_id AND customer_id = i_customer_id)
 ELSE 
   INSERT INTO wpcheap_items_selected(item_id,customer_id,quantity) VALUES (i_item_id, i_customer_id, i_quantity)
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você possui vários erros de sintaxe nessa procedure, segue o código correto:
Faltavam alguns ;

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SEND_ITEMS;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE SEND_ITEMS(
        IN i_item_id int(11), 
        IN i_customer_id VARCHAR(11),
        IN i_quantity SMALLINT
)
BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT item_id,customer_id FROM wpcheap_items_selected WHERE (item_id = i_item_id AND customer_id = i_customer_id))) THEN

        UPDATE wpcheap_items_selected 
            SET quantity = i_quantity 
        WHERE (item_id = i_item_id 
            AND customer_id = i_customer_id);

     ELSE 

         INSERT INTO wpcheap_items_selected(
                item_id,
                customer_id,
                quantity) 
        VALUES (
                i_item_id, 
                i_customer_id, 
                i_quantity);

    END IF;
END 
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Funcionou